# Linux virtual machine for command line (non-GUI) usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am on a laptop running Windows 10. I would like to make a virtual machine on this laptop that runs Ubuntu Linux. However, I only want this virtual machine for command line (non-GUI) operation. I have installed CygWin on my laptop, but it does not suit my needs. Is there any easy way to create this virtual machine? Thanks for any possible help.

Comment: just use the media to install and remove any desktop enviroment from the setup

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: just install this media https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD it's a minimal ubunti without desktop enviroment.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way would be to install [ubuntu server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), because it doesn't install by default a GUI.

Answer (score 3):

The question depends on that you call "the Ubuntu terminal."  As far as I know, no such beast exists.

A [computer] terminal is something like a VT100. It looks like this:

[image]

<sup>A DEC terminal. Image from Wikipedia</sup>

Almost all linux distribution ship with terminal emulators, usually running half a dozen of them on a TTY. **Optionally** they also ship with a graphical environment.

Now guessing on your post you want to create a VM and install Ubuntu on it. If you do not install the graphical part (Hence Francisco Tapia's comment on desktop environment) then you will get an Ubunto installation with a pure text setup.

Alternatively you you install it with all its default settings, and just SSH in.

> Is there any easy way to create this virtual machine?

Yes. Install VMware player or any similar hypervisor and start Ubuntu installation as normal.

Comment: I've just suggested an edit to clarify the question as I clicked on it thinking that it was related to the Linux Terminal Server Project.

Comment: @Hennes you started my day with a smile :), personally i think our OP is very new in this world but who we are to judge him, thats why i like your answer.

Comment: I agree. As asked the question is unclear and shows limited knowledge of what the OP is trying to do. So I had some educative fun (and hopefully this actually thought a few things) and tried to end with a constructive note. Now the big questions is going to be: Does the OP know what a VM is. And does he/she really want a VM or something else (e.g. just a windows 10 setup with all the Ubuntu tools available from a cmd.exe prompt and a shared disk). I guess we'll learn in time.